# PHP key value pair array to strings

Tags: php, arrays, string

Let's say I have an array that looks like this:

```
$args = array(
  'format' => 'file',
  'type' => 'page',
  'name' => 'Projects',
  'template' => 'default'
);
```

To get the values from the array keys I need to do this:

```
echo $args['format'];
echo $args['type'];
echo $args['name'];
echo $args['template'];
```

While it works, it feels more messy than needed. Is there a proper way to somehow convert it to this?

```
echo $format;
echo $type;
echo $name;
echo $template;
```

I'm aware of [list](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php) but that only uses values and not keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php ?

```
$args = array(
  'format' => 'file',
  'type' => 'page',
  'name' => 'Projects',
  'template' => 'default'
);
extract($args);

echo "$format, $type, $name, $template";
```

Output:

`file, page, Projects, default`

Comment: That's THE function. Works perfect!

Answer (score -2):

We can easily print the array value using foreach() loop if we don't use to list() as you mention then use `extract()` method like below:

```
$args = array(
        'format' => 'file',
        'type' => 'page',
        'name' => 'Projects',
        'template' => 'default'
    );
     extract($args);

    echo $format."<br/>".$type."<br/>".$name."<br/>".$template;
```